# Fade In body Background image

Tags: jquery, image, css

I have an ACF image field that is visible in every post, page and category page. This filed is used to add a different background image to the body of any post, page of category page. I am just wondering if it is possible to fade in these body images with a certain delay after the page loads. Haven't really been able to find any solutions for this so far.

Answer (score 0):

you can set jquery libery and set fade method in jquery try this

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/background.cycle.js"></script>

imageUrls: [
'res/img/bg1.jpg',
'res/img/bg2.jpg',
'res/img/bg3.jpg'
...
],

imageUrls: [],
duration: 5000,
fadeSpeed: 1000,
backgroundSize:
SCALING_MODE_NONE, SCALING_MODE_STRETCH, SCALING_MODE_COVER, SCALING_MODE_CONTAIN
```

Comment: The issue is the images are being added dynamically through an image field in ACF..