# Fading body background images when clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For duplicating alerts, please read the whole question. I AM NOT SEARCHING FADING TRANSITION IMAGE BACKGROUND ON A DIV. What i want is a fading transition of the whole body background image when clicking one of the buttons as show in the snippet. Making a wrapping div could be a solution, but is not the answer i'm looking for.

I found many answers for fading background-images on div but not on the whole body.

[Cross fading images](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/)

There are some negative answers from 2010, i guess there will be something new around. 
And similar questions with no answer at all:

[Fade In body Background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35860217/fade-in-body-background-image)

I´ve got a good solution for fading the body background-color using jquery-ui.js:

[Fading background color](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47115458/5351575)

But doesn´t work with background-images. Here is the example:

```js
$("#btn1").click(function() {
 $('body').removeClass();
 $('body').addClass('class1',1000, "easeOutBounce" );
});

$("#btn2").click(function() {
 $('body').removeClass();
 $('body').addClass('class2',1000, "easeOutBounce" );
});

$("#btn3").click(function() {
 $('body').removeClass(); 
 $('body').addClass('class3',1000, "easeOutBounce" );
});
```

```css
body {align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
text-align: center;
}
body.class1 {
background-image: url(https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-10uYQ232GmA/VB2cCRa0pDI/AAAAAAAAGgw/m9nRdE1d-Rg/s1600/checkerboard-tile-pattern.jpg);
background-repeat:repeat;
}
body.class2 {
background-image: url(http://www.subdude-site.com/WebPages_Local/RefInfo/Computer/WebDev/WebPageTiles/tilesTiles/tile_pattern_marbleTiles_bright_green_256x256.jpg);
background-repeat:repeat;

}
body.class3 {
background-image: url(https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-mCCWT2Qsqe4/UhHnOaJW7KI/AAAAAAAAFRo/4FHJyJdAeko/s1600/glossy-blue-ceramic-tiles-pattern.jpg);
background-repeat:repeat;

}
button {padding: 15px 32px;
margin: 80px 10px;
font-size: 16px;
border-radius: 12px;
border: 2px solid black;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="class1">
<button id="btn1">01</button>
<button id="btn2">02</button>
<button id="btn3">03</button>
</body>
```

Comment: fading transitions between each background

Comment: just add those lines in css to each body.class{
` -webkit-transition: background 1000ms ease-in-out 200ms; 
    -moz-transition: background 1000ms ease-in-out 200ms;
    -o-transition: background 1000ms ease-in-out 200ms;
    transition: background 1000ms ease-in-out 200ms;`

Comment: Doesn't fade, just stop the appearance of the next background a while.

Comment: Which browser are you using? For me it works fine in Chrome,

Comment: No in Codepen Firefox or Chrome:  https://codepen.io/danielillo/pen/pdyQyd

Comment: oh, i see, for me the same issue, however in jsfiddle in chrome it looks ok; https://jsfiddle.net/qbqyjh95/1/
p.s. but in firefox there is definitely an issue

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for @Roman Habibi, I just saw the jsfiddle on Chrome Android and works perfect. A pity it doesn't in all browsers.